# Change header on specific page wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change my header (all header : logo + menu) on specific pages of my wordpress.
EDIT : I didn't precise something important, in my mind, I woudl like to change the header on specific page AND tagged post.
Example : header test on page id 4, and post 3,4 & 5 wich are tag "test".

How can I manage that easily ?

I tried some plugins without success :

- WP Display Header
- Page Specific Menu Items
- Menu Swapper

I have the idea to change it with an if statement, but I'm worried about maintaining this code in time (I'm thinking about WordPress or Theme updates).

Have you already do that ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php if(is_page(<page id>)) { ?>

--------- Header 1 -----

<?php } else { ?>


--------- Header 2 -------- 

<?php } ?>
```

Add this code according to your header sections in header.php of your theme.

Comment: That's a way I was thinking about. But what about updates ?
Would I to rewrite the code in header.php ?

Comment: Yes @AlbertoV You need to update the code in header.php file

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work because I'm using a premium theme which have his own API to call WordPress functions... It seems to be very hard to change a simple function like that :/

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `get_header()` an optional parameter is the name of the header, you can see this in:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/

You need to create, for instance, header-another.php and put the code in it, after this only need calls `get_header('another')`.

Probabilly you need to create a custom template for the page that has a different header and call `get_header('another')` instead `get_header()` in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use different headers on different pages. For this example, we'll say we want to include header "one" in `productOne-page.php` and header "two" in `productTwo-page.php`).

First, create two header files, namely `header-one.php` and `header-two.php`.

To include header "one" in your `productOne-page.php` file, call: `get_header('one');`. Note that the argument should be the part of the header's filename *after the hyphen (`-`)*.

To include header "two" in your `productTwo-page.php` file, call `get_header('two');`.

To include the default header in any file you can just call `get_header();` with no arguments.

I hope this will help you. :)

Comment: Thank you for helping :)
What about updating Wordpress & Theme, will the change be conserve after updating files ?

Comment: Hello @AlbertoV nice to hear that it will help you. for your query about updating wordpress & theme. the answer is child theme. best practice is make a child theme of your theme and customise that according to your need.so whenever you perform update on theme it your customisation on child theme not reflect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the plugin [Page Menu (by Rohit Kumar)](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/page-menu/) to change the menu and the Haninder Singh solution to change the header and it work perfect.